# Use rsync to change only the date modified of folders/files

Tags: bash, rsync

I just transferred 1.8TB of data from an external hard drive to an internal hard drive using rsync, but I didn't add the "-t" flag, so the "Date Modified" for every file on the internal hard drive is now the date I ran rsync.

Is there a way to copy the dates from the source files to the destination files without having to delete the destination files and run rsync again with the "-t" flag?

Answer (score 1):

Recursive with `find` and `touch`

```
cd /source/dates/dir
find . -exec touch -c -m -r {} /destination/dates/dir/{} \;
```

Changing directory is important in order to get a relative path with `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Touching 'modified' to a file from another reference file can not be done with rsync.

However we can user the [**`touch`**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/touch.1.html) command to do so.

```
touch -m -r source/path/file dest/path/file
```

Above will touch the 'modified' date from the source to the destination file path.

This can further be scripted, e.g. below for all files in a given destination directory provided filenames are identical:

```
 for i in *; do touch $i -m -r /path/to/source/$i; done
```

Comment: Thanks Takkat! I'm looking for something that will be recursive through multiple directories. Somebody on another forum posted the following:
'find /home/abcdefg/ -exec touch {} \;
The abcdefg directory itself will be included. '

Comment: Never used find before though. Not entirely sure what the brackets or the final slash do either.

Comment: @user217685: yeah `find` is better for recursiveness. The `{}` is a placeholder for the filename found, however after doing a quick test yesterday I did not get desired results on different paths so I posted the loop approach.